# How to include sprint cloud dependency in gradle

Tags: gradle, spring-cloud

I am newbie in Gradle and don't know how manage dependency management.
Following is the build.gradle file that I have created.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.RELEASE")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

when I run gradlew without cloud dependency that everything being compiled but if compile with cloud then it gives me following error in Test which works perfectly fine with cloud.

Could someone help on this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hoxton isn't compatible with boot 2.4.0. try 2020.0.0-M6

Comment: when I changed the version then it gives me another error.

screenshot attached.

Comment: the screenshot shows, m1, but it's m6 located in https://repo.spring.io/milestone